# How to design this DB structure in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am now stuck on how to implement a more complicated (at least for me) database structure, which seems to me like a dynamic number of columns in a table.

What I need is to create an SQL table/s for a shuttle module that will store many shuttles which each has a different number of seats and every seat should have a different price.

For example:
One row: a shuttle with 8 seats, seat #1 = $20, seat #2 = $15, seat #3 = $13 ... seat #8 = $7.
One row: a shuttle with 16 seats, seat #1 = $25, seat #2 = $22, seat #3 = $20 ... seat #16 = $15.

The solution should handle different types of shuttles, one with 8 seats, one with 16 or any other number of seats depends on what number of seats the admin wish to add.

Now, I thought about few methods and I think both are not good enough.

**1. My first idea is** to create a table with a maximum of 16 columns for seats, all NULLable and then the admin inserts the new shuttle with numbers of seats needed and the rest will be NULL. I feel this is a really bad idea.
Let's ignore the case if the admin wants to add more than 16 seats which is a huge drawback, that is how the table will look like:

```
Table: shuttle
Columns: id, name, num_of_seats, seat_1_price, seat_2_price, seat_3_price..., seat_16_price
```

Then a row in this table might look like this:

```
1, Florida Shuttle, 8, 20, 15, 10, 8..., 5, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

I am 100% sure this approach is wrong.

**2. My second idea is** to create 2 tables, one to store the shuttle detail will be called "shuttles" and second to store the shuttle_seats_price relation, for example:

```
table: shuttles
columns: id, name, num_of_seats

table2: shuttle_seats_price
columns: id, shuttle_id, seat_number, seat_price
```

A typical entry in this structure will look like:

```
table: shuttles
columns: id, name, num_of_seats
row: 2, Florida Shuttle, 8

table 2: shuttle_seats_price
columns: id, shuttle_id, seat_number, seat_price
row: 1, 2, 1, 20
row: 1, 2, 2, 15
row: 1, 2, 3, 13
row: 1, 2, 4, 11
...
row: 1, 2, 8, 5
```

So to conclude, I need to create a solution to store different shuttles with unpredictable number of seats that each seat has different value of price, one table does not seem the right solution to me because as I see it, it is not a good approach to create 100 columns, each column for each seat and start inflating it with NULL values.

Thanks in advance! I hope I asked it very clear!

Comment: A database is a repository for information, not a computational engine.  Do your task in a programming language other than SQL.

Comment: May you please give a more detailed answer? Currently, I need the data to be stored somewhere and this data is dynamic, the admin is creating few shuttles each has a different amount of seats with different prices and the user has the option to choose which shuttle he wants... there is no way to implement it?

Comment: Store changes in the database when they occur.  Each time you want a shuttle, load the entire dataset, munch on it in PHP (or Java or VB or ...), deliver the answer.

Comment: OK, it may be possible in SQL.  But I would rather program it in some other language than SQL.

Comment: OK thank you for your answer, let me see if I understand what you're suggesting, creating only one table for shuttles, adding a column called seats_prices and store it in comma delimited format? like this: 20, 15, 13, 10? and then taking the prices, doing some PHP and program it that way? is that a good approach? by the way, how can it be implemented in SQL? how will you create this such thing? because I already had a similar issue before, creating a table with an unknown number of columns because sometimes it is necessary more columns then created same in this example for a number of seats.

Comment: OK, After I confirmed that storing records with CSV format is really a bad approach, and I don't have a NoSQL database on the server, and there isn't intent to move to another server, I now know that this is a question more of how to make the SQL work as NoSQL, each shuttle has different number of seats and each seat has different price, what's the best suggestion? how to store it in the MySQL? as you said, I will try to combine between SQL and PHP, but how do you suggest to store this data in SQL?

Comment: Table with shuttle_num, seat_num, price_for_seat.  Lots of rows, but it has all the info?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117848/discussion-between-eliran-levi-and-rick-james).

Answer (score 1):

I would create 2 tables: Shuttle and Seat.

You read it like this, a shuttle can have multiple seats, but a seat is connected to only 1 shuttle.

So you create a shuttle, and add the amount of seats you want to it.

I've made a UML diagram so you can see it yourself

[image]

EDIT: Adjusted the picture

EDIT2: Also remove the "RowId" Attribute from the shuttle, it was a mistake from me.

EDIT3: Also the #seats isn't really required. For example if you want the number of seats from shuttle with ID 3 you can simply do :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM seats WHERE shuttle_id = '3';
```

The result of this query will be the amount of seats in that shuttle.

Answer (score 0):

**|** Shuttle identified by number `SHTNUM` has maximum `MAX_SEATNUM` seats.

*For each shuttle, that shuttle has exactly one maximum number of seats;
more than one shuttle can have the same maximum number of seats.*

```
Shuttle {SHTNUM, MAX_SEATNUM}
    KEY {SHTNUM}
```

**|** Shuttle `SHTNUM` has seat number `SEATNUM` priced at `PRICE` dollars.

*For each shuttle, that shuttle has more than one seat number.*

*For each seat number, that number may exist in more than one shuttle.*

*Each seat is identified by the combination of SHTNUM, SEATNUM.*

*Each seat has exactly one price, for each price it is possible that more than one seat has that price.*

*For each seat number in each shuttle, that seat number is greater than 0.*

```
ShuttleSeat {SHTNUM, SEATNUM, PRICE}
        KEY {SHTNUM, SEATNUM}
FOREIGN KEY {SHTNUM} REFERENCES Shuttle {SHTNUM}

CHECK SEATNUM > 0
```

*For each seat number in each shuttle, that seat number is less or equal to MAX_SEATNUM for that shuttle.*

```
-- You will need to implement this constraint 
-- in the application code or using triggers.
```

---

[image]